# How to rename multiple services in Angular Js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, migration, angular-ui-bootstrap

The code base  , I am currently working is build upon AngularJs 1.4.6.I have migrated to angular 1.5.11 and as a result Angular-UI needs to be upgraded as well. When upgrading to angularUI bootstrap to version  0.14.3, the breaking changes were the renaming of prefixes. Earlier it was `$modal` & `$modalInstance` now it is `$uibModal` & `$uibModalInstance`.

The earlier syntax for using this service in a controller was this :

```
angular.module('main').controller('mainctrl',function($scope,$modal...) {

$scope.open  = function() {
        var modalInstance = $modal.open({
            templateURL: 'modal.html',
            controller: 'modalCtrl',
            size : 'md',
            resolver : {
                data: function() {
                    return $scope.items;
                }
            }
        })
        modalInstance.result.then(function() {}, function () {});
    }
    });
angular.module('main').controller('modalCtrl',function($scope,$modalInstance,data) {
console.log(data);
});
```

Now $modal and $modalInstance are both deprecated 
Since this service is used in over 50+ controllers and is called many times. I thought to rename this service instead of changing it.

Here's what I did:

```
.factory('$modal',function($uibModal){
return $uibModal;
});
```

and inject it into the required controller:

```
angular.module('main',function($scope,$modal...) {
/**
});
```

now the deprication warning is not coming for $modal but when i did the same for $modalInstance then the warning is coming.
[image: Deprecation warning]
Here's the code That I implemented:

```
.factory('$modalInstance',function($uibModalInstance){
return $uibModalInstance;
});
```

So how can I solve this? I also need to do this for over 20 other services that have their prefixes changed. Do, I need to create 20 factory methods or it can be done in another way?

Answer (score 0):

This is not good in long term when someone can be confused about what is really used. It also can raise unstable result when some factory be same named as with $modalInstance (This factory still exist in angularUI as you see in warning message).

I will prefer simple solution "Find & Replace", it just one time and you will never have to think about it again :).